# python - Letter Frequency

Tags: python

Write a Python function called hist() which takes a string as an argument, and creates a visual representation of the frequency of its alphabetic letters by printing each letter in uppercase the number of times it appears in the string, with each letter on a separate line, grouped from most to least.

Comment: Please post what you have done so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is similar, you don't need to read the file.

```
def hist(inputstr):
    lowlet = inputstr.upper()
    alphas = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.upper()
    occurrences = dict( (letter, 0) for letter in alphas)
    total = 0
    for letter in lowlet:
        if letter in occurrences:
            total += 1
            occurrences[letter] += 1
    letcount = sorted(occurrences.iteritems(),key = lambda x:-x[1])
    for letter, count in letcount:
        if count>0:
             print letter*count
```

Comment: it works perfect.. thanxx.. but am just not sure this is who it was supposed to done bcz in question it ask to Write a Python function called hist().

Comment: ohh, we can write it as a function too, I will update the answer.

Comment: for some reason i cant run this

Comment: @Sarah, it should be fixed now. The problem was in constructing the dict `occurrences` in the original code.

Comment: idk wats rong but still dont do anything when i run it.. but thnxx alot for ur help

Comment: It won't do anything when you run it. After you run this code, it will define a function, then you need to do `hist('William Shakespeare')` or something similar for the result.

Comment: than where do i see the output

Comment: @Sarah, the output will be in the console/text window. Are you using ipython?

Comment: bcz widout def a function i could see the out as asked in question

Answer (score 2):

A MUCH simpler approach is:

```
import string
def hist(s):
    d = {}
    for i in s.upper():
        if i.isalpha():
            d[i] = d[i] + 1 if i in d else 1
    for k in sorted(d.keys()):
        print k*d[k]
```